# Issue with Jhipster webapp since install of jenkins : openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed

Tags: maven, jenkins, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a maven spring mvc angularjs project (Jhipster) that used to run well.
I have installed Jenkins this morning on the same computer (on port 8081) plugged with BitBucket for the continuous integration, and ran a build.
Since, I can't run my app locally (with intellij or through terminal).
I am getting this error :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/techvalley/dev/tools/Intellij/idea-IU-163.11103.6/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/techvalley/dev/workspace/tecfel/target/classes:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-annotation/3.1.2/metrics-annotation-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-ehcache/3.1.2/metrics-ehcache-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.10.1/ehcache-2.10.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-graphite/3.1.2/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-healthchecks/3.1.2/metrics-healthchecks-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.2/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-jvm/3.1.2/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-servlet/3.1.2/metrics-servlet-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-servlets/3.1.2/metrics-servlets-3.1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate4/2.6.5/jackson-datatype-hibernate4-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-hppc/2.6.5/jackson-datatype-hppc-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/carrotsearch/hppc/0.7.1/hppc-0.7.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.6.5/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-json-org/2.6.5/jackson-datatype-json-org-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/bundles/json/20090211_1/json-20090211_1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.4.0/springfox-swagger2-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.6/swagger-annotations-1.5.6.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.6/swagger-models-1.5.6.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.4.0/springfox-spi-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.4.0/springfox-core-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.4.0/springfox-schema-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.4.0/springfox-swagger-common-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.4.0/springfox-spring-web-2.4.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/classmate-1.3.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j/1.2.1/liquibase-slf4j-1.2.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/ryantenney/metrics/metrics-spring/3.1.3/metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/2.4.3/HikariCP-2.4.3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-ehcache-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-envers/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-envers-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.4.2/liquibase-core-3.4.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-jdk8/1.0.0.Final/mapstruct-jdk8-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-configuration-processor-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20140107/json-20140107.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.8/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.32/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-juli-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.4.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-mail/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-mail-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.5/javax.mail-1.5.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-config-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.8/ognl-3.0.8.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.3.3/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.3.3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.6/groovy-2.4.6.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/net/logstash/logback/logstash-logback-encoder/4.6/logstash-logback-encoder-4.6.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-core/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-core-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-data/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-data-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.4.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-core-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/fr/ippon/spark/metrics/metrics-spark-reporter/1.2/metrics-spark-reporter-1.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.8.2/joda-time-2.8.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/6.3.0/jasperreports-6.3.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js5/itext-2.1.7.js5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/138/bcmail-jdk14-138.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/138/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bctsp-jdk14/1.38/bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/1.38/bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/1.38/bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jcommon/1.0.23/jcommon-1.0.23.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.19/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/4.3.1/ecj-4.3.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/castor/castor-xml/1.3.3/castor-xml-1.3.3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/castor/castor-core/1.3.3/castor-core-1.3.3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/stax/stax/1.2.0/stax-1.2.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.5.1/lucene-core-4.5.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.5.1/lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queryparser/4.5.1/lucene-queryparser-4.5.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-queries/4.5.1/lucene-queries-4.5.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-sandbox/4.5.1/lucene-sandbox-4.5.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/jakarta-regexp/jakarta-regexp/1.4/jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/olap4j/olap4j/0.9.7.309-JS-3/olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/core-2.3.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/57.1/icu4j-57.1.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts/6.0.0/jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/getsentry/raven/raven-logback/7.8.0/raven-logback-7.8.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/com/getsentry/raven/raven/7.8.0/raven-7.8.0.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar:/home/techvalley/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/techvalley/dev/tools/Intellij/idea-IU-163.11103.6/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.techvalley.tecfel.TecfelApp
2017-02-17 11:47:19.236 ERROR 14313 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring.log (Permission non accordée)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:301)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.techvalley.tecfel.TecfelApp.main(TecfelApp.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I haven't changed anything on my source code.
I don't know if Jenkins has something to do with this error.
I have no idea how to solve this problem (the problem also occurs on other projects that run with the same architecture).
If someone has an idea...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The file /tmp/spring.log likely exists and is owned by another user. It hangs on startup when trying to write to it.

I worked around this by adding

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="./logs/"/>
```

To a logback-spring.xml file.

See: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml